# REGEX to match domain TLD from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex

working on DNS project where need to get all TLD domains. using php and mysql

I have tried as below to get all **.COM** domains:

```
SELECT * FROM `domains` WHERE `host_name` LIKE '%.com'
```

But it is not working properly some time, i google and found that i can be done by **REGEX** so now can you please help me to get **proper** and **faster** way to get TLD domains. table contains more than 100M hostname

Comment: why not in PHP?

Comment: because i think mysql will be faster than check it php

Comment: faster way? add a tld column.

Comment: agreed with @CasimiretHippolyte: otherwise it be difficult to catch

Comment: yes i have added all TLD on other table but not using it on join query

Comment: *But it is not working properly some time* - how?

Comment: Fastest would be to add TLD to the same table. Regex probably won't be that much faster than LIKE. But what do you mean it _doesn't work_. Do you have bad data, like trailing spaces? Cleaning those in data entry surely is the fastest way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it look like some other error of phpmyadmin: pls check screenshot url: http://prntscr.com/d4yvzt

Comment: Why two different kind of ticks, \` vs '? If table and column names have only A-Za-z0-9, they are needed only around '%.com'